# System.Exception : The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'.- xunit and moq

Tags: .net, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq, iqueryable

I am working with xunit and moq.

I am trying to test `FindAsyncTestAsync` method return something (not null) using xUnit and Moq.

I have instantiated all the required mock repository instances using constructor. I have also instantiated the `ParticipantService` in the test method.

```
[Fact]
public async Task FindAsyncTestAsync()
{
    var participantList = ParticipantMockData.ListAllAsyncEntity(); // not null. length is 2

   _participantRepository.Setup(_ => _.FindAsync(new Guid("ffbf486f-bf31-4bb4-8fc2-5beaae59e127")))
         .Returns(Task.FromResult(participantList[0]));   // something is wrong here. I don't know

   var sut = new ParticipantService(
     _participantRepository.Object,
     _participantSupportNeed.Object,
     _participantConnection.Object,
     _participantDisability.Object,
     _participantMedicalCondition.Object,
     _supportNeed.Object,
     _disabilityn.Object,
     _medicalCodition.Object,
     _participantApplicationUser.Object,
     _appLogger.Object);

   var result = await sut.FindAsync(new Guid("ffbf486f-bf31-4bb4-8fc2-5beaae59e127"));

   Assert.NotNull(result);

   Assert.Equal(participantList[0].Id, result?.Id);
 }
```

Test respond is:

```
 Message: 
    System.Exception : The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

IRepository.cs

```
public interface IRepository<E> where E : IEntityBase
{
    Task<List<E>> ListAsync(bool withInactives = false);
    IQueryable<E> AsNoTracking(bool withInactives = false);
    Task<E?> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues);
}
```

FindAsync method in ParticipantService

```
   public async Task<ParticipantAsyncModel?> FindAsync(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            var participant = await participantRepository.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(a => a.Id == id)
            .Include(a => a.ParticipantAddresses)
            .Include(a => a.ParticipantConnections)!.ThenInclude(a => a.Connection)
            .Include(a => a.ParticipantApplicationUsers)!.ThenInclude(a => a.ApplicationUser)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            var participantView =
                 new ParticipantAsyncModel()
                 {
                    // object removed for simplistic 
                 };

            if (participantView is null) return null;

            var participantModel = participantView.Adapt<ParticipantAsyncModel>();
            return participantModel;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

How can I find the problem?

Comment: FindAsync in the service should call the repo's FindAsync (the method you mocked)

Comment: Without make changes in service class, is there any way to write test for FindAsync method?. (I am new to unit test, Plz help me)

Answer (score 0):

> // something is wrong here. I don't know

Nothing is with the setup *per se*, it will work for `IRepository.FindAsync` call just fine, the problem here is that you are not invoking this method in `ParticipantService.FindAsync`, you are invoking `IRepository.AsNoTracking` which obviously was not setup correctly. As a quick fix you can use [EF Core in-memory database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) to return from  `IRepository.AsNoTracking` mock, but I would say you should reconsider the whole solution design.

There are quite a lot of developers which consider using (generic) repository over EF as antipattern (for example because EF is already implementing repository pattern, as well as Unit Of Work), but even if you are not ready to make such drastic design changes, you should consider scrapping method returning `IQueryable` from the repository due to the "leaky abstraction" created here - clients (like `ParticipantService` in `FindAsync`) rely on the `IQueryable` returned from the method to be EF Core `IQueryable` (or something which supports all EF Core extension methods like `AsNoTracking`, `Include`, etc., see [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions?view=efcore-7.0)), which is why you have the exception in question.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking AsNoTracking is working for me.

```
            //1 - create a List<T> with test items
            var participantList = ParticipantMockData.ListAllAsyncEntity();

            //2 - build mock by extension
            var mock = participantList.AsQueryable().BuildMock();

            //3 - setup the mock as Queryable for Moq
            _participantRepository.Setup(x => x.AsNoTracking(false)).Returns(mock);


            var sut = new ParticipantService(
            _participantRepository.Object, _participantSupportNeed.Object, _participantConnection.Object, _participantDisability.Object, _participantMedicalCondition.Object, _supportNeed.Object, _disability.Object, _medicalCondition.Object, _participantApplicationUser.Object, _appLogger.Object);

            var result = await sut.FindAsync(new Guid("ffbf486f-bf31-4bb4-8fc2-5beaae59e127"));
```